# Entity Framework Core : insert error (Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Action' instances are not supported. Path: $.MoveNextAction.)

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, repository

I am trying to preform a insert action using Entity Framework Core 6.0.11 with identity framework as the base, with Postgres as the database.

I am getting the following error when trying to preform an insert operation:

> Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Action' instances are not supported. Path: $.MoveNextAction

This is the code of my insert:

```
public async Task<CampaignDetialDto> CreateCampaign(BaseCampaignDto campaignDto)
{
    var userCampaign = new UserCampaign
    {
        UserId = UserId,
        Campaign = _mapper.Map<Campaign>(campaignDto),
        CampaignRole = CampaignRoleEnum.Player
    };

    await _userCampaignRepo.AddAsync(userCampaign);
    return _mapper.Map<CampaignDetialDto>(userCampaign.Campaign);
}
```

The userCampaignRepo:

```
public class UserCampaignRepository : GenericRepository<UserCampaign>, IUserCampaignRepository
{
    private readonly PostGresContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public UserCampaignRepository(PostGresContext context, IMapper mapper) : base(context, mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
}
```

The base repo preforming the action:

```
public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
{
    await _context.AddAsync(entity);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return entity;
}
```

The context and models:

```
public class PostGresContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public PostGresContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserCampaign> UserCampaigns { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleConfiguration());

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserCampaign>().HasKey(x => new
        {
            x.UserId,
            x.CampaignId
        });
    }
}

public class UserCampaign
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public virtual Campaign Campaign { get; set; }

    public CampaignRoleEnum CampaignRole { get; set; } = CampaignRoleEnum.Player;
}

public class Campaign
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public ActiveStateEnum Active { get; set; } = ActiveStateEnum.Active;

    public virtual ICollection<UserCampaign> UserCampaigns { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserCampaign> UserCampaigns { get; set; }
}
```

```
public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationPostGresContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration _config)
{
    services.AddDbContext<PostGresContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseNpgsql(_config.GetConnectionString("PostGresConnectionString"));
    });

    return services;
}
```

I tried altering the add methods hoping it might bring a change but with no effect, I also tried to call the context directly by using `_context.addAsync(XXX)` or `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` - this also had the same results.

I would like to add a model into the Postgres database.